# How to install google.cloud automl_v1beta1 for python using anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, google-cloud-automl

Google Cloud AutoML has python example code for detection, but I have error when importing these modules

```
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1
from google.cloud.automl_v1beta1.proto import service_pb2
```

It says `cannot import name automl_v1beta1`. I know it's a common problem and there are many solutions on internet but nothing has worked so far. I'm using Windows 10 and run python 2.7 on Anaconda environment.

I tried these, but nothing worked :

```
conda install -c conda-forge google-cloud-sdk
conda install -c conda-forge google-cloud-storage 
python -m pip install google-cloud
pip install google-cloud-automl
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just solved it and it's a very simple problem. I reinstall `google-cloud-automl` using below command and works.

```
pip.exe install google-cloud-automl
```

Why it didn't work last time I tried it? It's because I didn't run anaconda prompt as **administrator**. The reason is when installing `google-cloud-automl` it will uninstall deprecated projects like `future`, like this :

```
Found existing installation: futures 3.1.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (futures) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling futures-3.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled futures-3.1.1
```

Future will be only successfully removed if I run the command as administrator. Last time it thrown authentication error that I didn't realize, so the re-installation process stopped. Hope it will help some people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages inside the Jupiter notebook cell, I hope it will work for you.
[image]